# Packaging java desktop application with references to open source licenses

Tags: java, javafx, windows-installer, dmg

We have a Java desktop application with DMG and MSI builds. When user installs the application I would like to have a licenses directory created with references to all the open source licenses in the application's installation directory.

I am able to download the licenses through the below plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>download-licenses</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>download-licenses</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But I am unable to package the license directory so that if user installs the application, the license directory is found in the application's installation directory.

How should I package my application to include a licenses folder?

Comment: So what is going wrong? When you do a "mvn package", do you get a target/generated-resources/licenses folder?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt  Yes the licenses folder is present in the generated-resources, but I would like to package licenses folder along with the msi or dmg package.

Or is there any other way to make user aware of the licenses the application is using?

Comment: How do you create the msi or DMG package?

Comment: @frant.hartm I make use of WIX to create msi installer and for both msi and DMG installers I use 'mvn jfx:native' command

Comment: This isn't really a Windows Installer question. It's a question for whatever tool you are using to author the MSI

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add licenses folder in the installation directory by adding

```
<additionalAppResources></additionalAppResources>
```

to the zenjava plugin which is used to build native build for windows and mac.